# Cout Vector in Random Coordinates n times

Tags: c++, vector, cout

I am trying to cout a vector 12 times in a loop at random coordinates. I have created my vector here:

```
vector<Item> sV(MAXPILLS, pill);
```

Currently it only prints one of the vector out. This is my code for the random coordinates of the vector and the attempt at printing 12 of them out. I'd appreaciate it if you could help!

```
    void generatePowerPills(char gr[][SIZEX], Item pill){
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        gr[pill.y][pill.x] = pill.symbol;
    }
}
void initialiseRandomPillsCoordinates(vector<Item>& sV) {
    //pass the vector to the function to give each pill random coordinates
    Seed();
    for (size_t i(0); i < sV.size(); ++i)
    {
        sV.at(i).y = Random(SIZEY - 2);    //vertical coordinate in range [1..(SIZEY - 2)]
        sV.at(i).x = Random(SIZEX - 2);    //horizontal coordinate in range [1..(SIZEX - 2)]
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `cout` line?

Comment: I am not using a cout. I am calling the vector within another function which then c's out ->

 initialiseGame(grid, spot, sV[MAXPILLS]);

Comment: Can you post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Otherwise, there isn't enough here for people to help you with.

Comment: Show your code. The `initialiseGame(grid, spot, sV[MAXPILLS]);` or whatever part that actually tries to print, etc. There is nothing to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just comment but sadly I can only answer. Anyway, you're iterating here:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    gr[pill.y][pill.x] = pill.symbol;
}
```

But where are you using "i" inside this loop? It seems it will do the same, 12 times. Unless there's some hidden functionality somewhere inside, if so, shame on me.

Comment: i declared the i to try to print 12 of the pills, however this is not working how i initially thought it would.

Comment: Ya, but it does nothing but assigns 12 times 'pill.symnbol' to 'gr[pill.y][pill.x]'. You'd have to either do the printing inside the loop, or somehow to 'gr[pill.y][pill.x] += pill.symbol' (or just add everything up to some vector passed by reference).

Comment: Tried the += it however this replaces the symbol with an arrow for some strange reason...

Comment: Ya, I forgot it's char not a string. How about passing a vector, pushing then result inside the loop, and the extracting this during/before printing?